# How to change reCAPTCHA v2 Image challenge to reCAPTCHA v2 Text challenge

Tags: php, recaptcha, moodle

As the title said How to change reCAPTCHA v2 Image challenge to reCAPTCHA v2 Text challenge.

I have a project that I want to change the captcha from Image to input text. How do I do that? My project using Moodle.

I've only tried adding reCAPTCHA to my moodle project and it work but the captcha is image challenge I want to change it to input text or number challenge.

Comment: I can see no indication in the documentation anywhere, that would suggest that that was even an available option with reCAPTCHA v2.

Answer (score 0):

I can't see a text or image option for reCaptcha - is it Google reCaptcha or another provider?

https://www.google.com/recaptcha/admin/create

The documentation says there is a "I'm a not a robot" checkbox or an invisible background check

https://developers.google.com/recaptcha/docs/versions

[image]